# Execute multiple threads each one for a certain amount of time in java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, executor

I'm sending files to my local server that creates a file back. My problem occurs when the user perform multiple actions one after another and I need to show an error message if one of the requests don't get a feedback file in 5 min.

How can I handle all these requests? I used `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` to check if the feedback file is there every minute but I don't know how to handle multiple ones and keep the countdown to each request for the 5 min case.
My try:

```
ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(listPrinter.size()));
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            try {

                final File retrievedFile = new File("/home/"+list.get(i)+".csv");

                ListenableFuture<File> future = executor.submit(new Callable<File>() {
                    public File call() {
                        // Actually send the file to your local server
                        // and retrieve a file back

                        if(retrievedFile.exists())
                        {
                            new Notification("file exits").show(Page.getCurrent());
                        }
                        else{
                            new Notification("file no exits").show(Page.getCurrent());
                        }
                        return retrievedFile;
                    }
                });
                future.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
                new Notification("Time out").show(Page.getCurrent());
            }
        }
```

But it just get executed at the beginning and that's it but when the file is added nothing happens.

Is it possible to do this with `watchService`? It works pretty well for me but I didn't know about the 5 min case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a `Timer` that is executed every `5` minutes getting all the `db` transactions that happened for the last 5 minutes and didn't get any response and show my error code. It works pretty good. Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the Future interface:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

should fit perfectly to your problem.

When you run a thread, the result could be a Future, it is the result of a asyncronous task, and you can have one Future per asyncronous task that you are launching.

```
Future<File> sendReceiveFile(File inputFile) {
    final Future<File> future = new YourFuture<File>(...);
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            File outputFile = null;
            try {
                 outputFile = SendFileToServer(inputFile);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                // do something
            } finally {
                future.setValue(fileOutput);
            }
        }
    }.start();
    return future;
}
```

And in your main:

```
Future<File> future = sendReceiveFile(myFile);
File outputFile = null;
try {
    outputFile = future.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTE);
} catch(TimeOutException e) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Using `new Thread() { }.start()` is not very robust. A `ThreadPoolExecutor` would let you control the number of threads, the size of the queue to use when the pool of threads is full, among other nice features.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this manually, but using [Guava ListenableFuture](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) would be much better:

```
// Here we create a fixed thread pool with 10 threads and an inifinite-capacity queue
ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));

final File fileToSend = ...; // 

ListenableFuture<File> future = executor.submit(new Callable<File>() {
    public File call() {
        // Actually send the file to your local server
        // and retrieve a file back
        File retrievedFile = YourLocalServer.sendAndRetrieve(fileToSend);
        return retrievedFile;
    }
});

Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<File>() {

    public void onSuccess(File retrievedFile) {
        // Handle the successfully retrieved file when it returns
    }

    public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
        // Handle the error
    }
});
```

By sending the file asynchronously, you can send and retrieve many files at any given time. Then, when the server responds (either with a retrieved file or with an error), you can handle the response (retrieved file or exception) just when it comes back, without needing to wait for it. This means that the `onSuccess()` or `onFailure()` methods will be automatically executed when there's a response available from your local server.

Comment: looks good but the problem is not to start multiple threads but to keep the countdown for the 5 min case for EACH request!

Comment: @user2137817 If you want to wait 5 minutes for *each* request to your local server, use [`future.get(timeout, unit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) instead of `Futures.addCallback()` and handle exceptions properly in a `try/catch` block.

Comment: the thing is I don't want to wait 5, it should be there in 1 min max but in case 5 min and nothing then it's an error or if I do the future.get(), it will wait 5 min no matter what

Comment: > if I do the future.get(), it will wait 5 min no matter what. This is not correct. `Future.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)` actually works the way you want. It waits until the response comes back, or fails with a `TimeoutException` if no response comes after 5 minutes.